# Mutalisks upgrade

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I use mutalisks a lot when I play zerg. What upgrades affect their performance. Are there other upgrades for them other than those from the spire?

Comment: Its kind of sad that the answer is just "no."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Flyer Attacks** (Attack Bonus, Spire)
- **Flyer Carapace** (Armor Bonus, Spire)

Nothing more, I'm afraid...

Comment: Always get Flyer attacks first, too -- each bounce benefits from the upgrade as well, so you're getting *much* more effective attack as long as you're facing more than 2 units. (So most always).

Comment: I just want add that with Mutas, imo, the more the better.  My first muta assualt might be 6 but if i'm in a team game and can get a few more, i'll shoot out with 10 and continue to mass.  A big ball of mutas can do some hefty hefty damage.